# Copy dynamic range from one sheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the below code to copy my data from  sheet1 to sheet2 and append the data in sheet2 if script runs again? The issue is that my range is not fixed in sheet 1,I want to copy whatever range contains the content should be copied to sheet2 Can anyone guide that what to change in the below code to get the result?

```
  function copyInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet2");

  var source = copySheet.getrange(2,1,200,7);
 var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,200,7);

  source.copyTo(destination, {contentsOnly:true});
   var data = copySheet.getRange(2,1,200,6)  
   data.clearContent()

   }
```

Comment: Provided that you are on the active sheet etc, then you could change `var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");` to `var copySheet = ss.getActiveSheet();`

Comment: Hey Is there anything which can be edited so that any data range can be copied from one sheet to other ?

Comment: If you mean that the range is not locked into the apps script itself, this would be possible by having an apps script with popup that asks for the range to be copied.

Comment: I am searching for a solution to automate the copying of data from one sheet to other 
for example sheet 1 intially contains 12 rows when we run the script it copies the 12 rows to sheet 2 then before next run sheet 1 contains 13 rows then if we run this it should append the sheet 2 data and add the rows after previous 12 rows.

Comment: no one can read your mind what you intent for the future, so please state exactly the problem you have and the solution you are looking for... in you post and not in conversation.. this will make it much easier for anyone who is trying to help you to provide a valid solution.

Comment: Probably it will help if you add screenshots: what you have, what you want to have. Step 1, Step 2, Step 3, Step 4... It looks like nobody (me included) can understand what's wrong with the code. It does about the job you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Method1:
Include:

```
var paste_lr = pasteSheet.getLastRow()
```

Modify:

```
  var source = copySheet.getrange(paste_lr+1,1,200,7);
```

Similarly change 200 using same function.

Method2:

```
var sp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var SourceLr = sp.getProperty("Source_Data_Rows") || 0;

var source = copySheet.getrange(SourceLr+1,1,200,7);

var Source_Lr = copySheet.getLastRow();
sp.setProperty("Source_Data_Rows", Source_Lr);
```

Comment: var paste_lr = pasteSheet.getLastRow()

  var copy_lr= copySheet.getlastrow()

  var source = copySheet.getrange(paste_lr+1,1,copy_lr,7);

  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,copy+lr,7);

Comment: Edited like the above code  but getting error, anything to change.